# how to stop a filter from continuing on a recordset or collection

Tags: php, lithium

So I have a variable and a recordset:

```
$firstRecordID = 1;
$records = Recordset::all();
```

I want to filter the recordset:

```
$filteredRecords = $records->find(function($record) use ($firstRecordID){
    return ($record->id == $firstRecordID);
});
```

In this example, assuming the record id is a primary key, there will only be one row that will get returned, however, I think the filter will keep on going.

My question is, how do I force the filter to stop after a certain condition is met?

edit: I'll add another more complex example:

```
$filteredRecords = $records->find(function($record) use ($lastRecordID){
    $conditions == $records->conditions;
    // in here I would find some value 
    // based on some other unknown record based on the $conditions

    // if the value matches any of the $conditions return the row
    // if the value matches a specified stop condition 
    // (which is defined by the user) stop retrieving rows.
});
```

Comment: It all depends on the code in your find() method which you have so thoughtfully provided.... oh! where is it?

Comment: @Mark Baker I believe its in the second code block, in between the braces. If you are referring to the the actual definition of the find method, I believe I tagged the question with lithium, which means the code is in git. Thanks for the sarcasm, it really doesn't help, or make sense for that matter.

Comment: Surely the far better option is to retrieve the record you want in the first place, not to retrieve all and then filter

Comment: @Mark Baker Perhaps I over simplified my example. Its true, according to the example, it would be far better to just specify the ID and retrieve the record. However, I'm using the call back to apply logic which the user provides to determine row by row if it fits the dynamic criterion. However, the number of candidate rows could be more then 10, more then I want to display on a page.

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to use first($filter)

```
$filteredRecords = $records->first(function($record) use ($firstRecordID){
    return ($record->id == $firstRecordID);
});
```

http://li3.me/docs/lithium/util/Collection::first

Comment: First would definitely work if the collection is always sorted and I'm always looking for the ID of 1, but what if it was a 3? The reason I need to stop is because I'm pulling the logic from user defined requirements which can change dynamically.

Comment: @ton.yeung Read the documentation that Tomen linked to. `Collection::first` returns the first filter match; it is not the same as `Model::first`. Processing will stop when the filter returns true.

Comment: My mistake, Tomen and @benzado, you guys are absolutely correct. I oversimplified my question though, so would you mind reading the comment I just left in the OP? I clarified why I'm asking the question, which would explain why this wouldn't work. I suppose in a nut shell, I want to stop iterating after a condition is met.

Comment: take another look at my answer and the first()-function in refer to. it does exactly what you want: iterate over each item and exit after your condition is met. i updated the answer by integrating your code to make it more clear

Comment: @Tomen It doesn't do what he wants, he wants multiple results, not the first one passing the test.

Answer (score -1):

## Short answer

Throw an exception inside the filter and catch it on the outside. You will probably have to collect the included items in an array yourself since you won't have access to `find`'s return value.

## Long answer

You are focusing too much on a particular tactic (stopping `find` using a filter) when it might do you some good to step back and consider what you are trying to accomplish.

It honestly sounds like you are trying to eat your cake and have it too: you want to be flexible and specify your search conditions in a function you can easily change, but you also want to be efficient and not pull more data out of the database than you have to.

The thing is, passing a filter function into `find` is already as inefficient as you can get it, because li3 will have to pull *every record from the database* before your filter is even called. *That's where the inefficiency is.* Stopping the filtering process once you hit 10 items or whatever won't make much of a difference (unless your filtering is also very expensive).

I would recommend thinking of the following:

1. Do you really need to allow any filter method at all? Is it possible to use declarative conditions? If so, you can supply `limit` options and let the database do all the work.
2. If you can't, consider using `find` to fetch a small batch of records and collect the ones you want to keep in an array. Repeat with another small batch until you've checked every item in the database or filled your array.

Comment: I'm running the find method on an existing recordset, so if my table has 10000 rows, and my recordset has 50, it will only iterate over 50 is how I thought it worked. Since find in this instance isn't static.

Comment: How expensive is your filtering? Can't you just filter the set of 50 and then take the first 10 of the results?

Comment: I think this is going off trac. I'm not trying to accomplish paging. I need to return a result set that the conditions for whether or not they will show is dynamic and embedded IN THE RESULT SET itself. I don't know what the conditions at design time, so the business logic extracts the conditions in the filter and determines if the row should be displayed.

Comment: i dont consider throwing an exception to obtain regular behavior a good idea.

Comment: @Tomen It's not good design, but if the requirements are to stop processing from within the filter code, and the API doesn't provide a way, that's pretty much the only option.